# Call Web API for 30K times within one hour of time period

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, threadpool

I need to call Web API(Hosted on different network) from windows application from users machine for 30,000 times within one hour of time span.

I tried Multithreading to achieve the same but it is not working(giving system out of memory exceprion).

I used TreadPool as below

```
private static object threadLock = new object();
public delegate void BarDelegate();

int ThreadCount = dtExcel.Rows.Count;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount - 1; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(output => CallAPI());
    }
}

public void CallAPI()
{
    string branchCode = "",
        para1 = dtExcel.Rows[progressBar.Value]["para1"].ToString(),
        para2 = "324",
        para3 = "Test",
        para4 = dtExcel.Rows[progressBar.Value]["para4"].ToString();
    //Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ": " + progressBar.Value);
    var service = new APIService();
    var resp = service.CallAPIService(para1, para2, para3, para4, para5);
    if (resp.IsSuccess == true)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dtGrdVwR = dataGrid.Rows[progressBar.Value];
        dtGrdVwR.Cells[3].Value = "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        DataGridViewRow dtGrdVwR = dataGrid.Rows[progressBar.Value];
        dtGrdVwR.Cells[3].Value = "Failed: "+ resp.Message;
    }
    try
    {
        this.Invoke(new BarDelegate(UpdateBar));
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

private void UpdateBar()
{

    lblEndTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    progressBar.Value++;
    if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum)
    {
        // We are finished and the progress bar is full.
    }
}
```

Here dtExcel has 30,000 records(Uploaded by user from excel) which needs to processed within one hour and update the status of executed record in respective row in dataGrid.

The API call is made over network where single call takes approximate 1 to 2 seconds to execute.

```
service.CallAPIService(para1, para2, para3, para4, para5);
```

The above method internally performs heavy task like request encryption and digital signature and response decryption and digital signature verification.

Please help me with the best way possible where i can perform the task within time period and without getting SystemOutOfmemoryException.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does the owner of this api know youre going to be hammering it 8.5 times a second for an hour a time? Surely it would be better to improve the API to accept blocks of data

Comment: Try it with async/await. Your operation is I/O bound so it is wasteful to spin up threads. Although I think you need a different approach regardless.

Comment: `int ThreadCount = dtExcel.Rows.Count;` - you want to start 30 thousand threads to do this?!

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes API owner is aware of the hits but we can not make any changes to the API because of some limitation.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am creating a ThreadPool for 30000 requests.

Comment: @Crowcoder Can you suggest any alternate approach to this.

Comment: While I don't have extensive experience with it, the [Akka.Net](https://getakka.net/) framework is supposed to be highly concurrent and scalable. You may need to distribute the work between a couple of servers, but maybe not.

Comment: Why are you not using parameters in your CallAPI ? This could make the thread lighter since it has no more need to keep all the dtexcel contain in it , ut need to reference only few of Strings which are actually the values of the single row.
 It is unclear if the out of memory error is happening to the system running your routine , so a smaller thread / class can solve it or if it is returned from the hosting API server, in the second option they need to reconfigure IIS or expand the system memory.

Comment: 300 simultaneous requests should be more than enough to account for communications delays.  And as Crowcoder said, using overlapped operations for simultaneous requests is better than multitudes of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code is horribly broken because of the race condition accessing `progressBar.Value`.  It's pointless to discuss any other issues, because you are going to totally reorganize your code to fix the race condition, rendering other comments obsolete.

Fix it so that you don't have N threads all trying to process item #1, and then ask a new question with your new code.